# Is it possible to use CoreLocation services with external GPS - NMEA?

Tags: ios, swift, gps, core-location

I am writing an app for iOS (I am using SwiftUI) which requires to work with external GPS receiver. GPS is not connected to the iPhone / iPad via bluetooth or something else.
GPS is sends NMEA strings to a raspberryPi and with UDP socket communication I get the strings in my app, where I split them and would like to use the latitude, longitude, speed, etc. from the external GPS.

My questions is, can I utilise somehow CoreLocation framework for that, or there is another way of doing that in Swift?

Comment: If your app is already reading the external location data then what would you use CoreLocation for? CoreLocation is only for built-in location services.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that is good news but … in that case, how can I use the map features in swift? Just by using same classes, methods but using my readings? I tried to find articles on google but to no success, do you have good articles that I can read?

Comment: See the documentation for MKMapView. You don't need to use CoreLocation to show a map. Though it makes it easy to show the user's current location using CoreLocation, you can implement your own logic as needed based on your remote location data.

Comment: I believe that if you have your peripheral implement the [Location and Navigation Service](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/location-and-navigation-service-1-0/) via BLE and then pair the peripheral with your iOS device then it will use the external GPS feed, but if you already have a connection between your app and the device, then it may not be worth the effort of implementing location and navigation service on the Raspberry Pi